# Get the most recent date without the MAX function... Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Yet another academic task that will have absolutely no place in the real world... This is what I have to do:

• Use an explicit cursor with a parameter that accepts car registration to find 
the most recent reservation made on the car. You will have to look at the 
date_reserved column from I_BOOKING table here. You cannot use the 
MAX function. Compare all the relevant dates to find the most recent one.

Honestly, I have no idea how else to do this outside of the MAX (or other) function.

So far I have this:

```
CURSOR reg_cr (registration VARCHAR2) IS
SELECT GREATEST (date_reserved)
FROM i_booking;
v_reg reg_cr%ROWTYPE;
```

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: google "oracle top n query"

Comment: ans: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries.php

Comment: Not sure how you'd use a top-n query with an explicit cursor; or rather without the cursor being pointless. Sounds like maybe they want you to have a variable holding the current latest date and compare each value from the cursor with it, updating the variable only if it's later? On the plus side, that might actually be useful one day, maybe, kinda.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of methods that return only one record:

```
SELECT date_reserved
FROM   (SELECT * FROM i_booking
        ORDER BY date_reserved DESC)
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;

SELECT DISTINCT
       FIRST_VALUE(date_reserved)
       OVER (ORDER BY date_reserved DESC)
FROM   i_booking;

SELECT date_reserved
FROM   (SELECT date_reserved
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_reserved DESC)
               AS the_rn
        FROM   i_booking)
WHERE  the_rn = 1;
```

This method may return multiple rows (if there is a tie for first place):

```
SELECT date_reserved
FROM   (SELECT date_reserved
              ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date_reserved DESC)
               AS the_rank
        FROM   i_booking)
WHERE  the_rank = 1;
```

[wildplasser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19400852/103295) also exhibits this feature.

Comment: How can I get this into an explicit cursor?

Comment: Thanks Jeff, however I can't use subqueries.

Comment: @Splunk, yes, you can. And your question never mentioned that limitation.

Comment: Yeah I did fail to mention that limitation, my apologies.  I can't use subqueries, in built functions, groups etc etc.  It is really quite painful.

Comment: Well, neither of the first two query examples require subqueries. By the way, imposing arbitrary restrictions on the question makes it much less likely to be useful to future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Although the wording of the assignment doesn't seem to explicitly preclude using a different built-in function, the spirit seems to me to be looking for a brute-force approach looping over all of the date values - particularly from the 'compare all the relevant dates' part, though that's still ambiguous. Depends what you've already learned about as well, I suppose.

So here's my take on what I thought the assignment was getting at:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  cursor reg_cur (registration i_booking.registration%type) is
    select date_reserved
    from i_booking
    where registration = reg_cur.registration;
  max_date date;
begin
  for reg_row in reg_cur('<reg value>') loop
    if max_date is null or reg_row.date_reserved > max_date then
      max_date := reg_row.date_reserved;
    end if;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('Most recent date is: ' || to_char(max_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
end;
/
```

This keeps track of the most recent date it's seen so far, and on each iteration of the loop, checks if the current cursor value if more recent. Horribly contrived of course, but that's what you seemed to be expecting.

It also isn't clear what you're supposed to do with the value; `dbms_output` also isn't suitable for any real world use here, so maybe you want a function; here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d322c/1) of the same approach in function form.

Comment: For some reason this is not outputting anything.  The table is definitely populated.

Comment: @Splunk - where are you running it? Did you include the `set serveroutput on` line, if you're running from SQL*Plus or SQL Developer (and you might need to run as a script, or open the `dbms_output` panel, there); other clients will vary. The function version ought to work anywhere...

Comment: I just realised it was because I didn't populate the ('<reg value>') in the loop.  Is there a way to make this work to show all distinct registrations rather than selecting one?

Comment: @Splunk - probably many ways. If you're learning about cursors, one way would be to have an outer cursor loop which gets the distinct registrations, and then calls this cursor for each of those values. Not really sure how you want it to work.

Comment: Pretty much, the end result I require is to have individual registrations and the most recent booking date for that registration displayed.  This has to show the registration and most recent booking date for every car, not just a specific one.  This is doing my head in.

Answer (score 1):

The *maximal value* means: there is no corresponding record with a higher value:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders oo                       -- all orders
WHERE NOT EXISTS (                   -- for which there does not exist
   SELECT * FROM orders nx           -- an order from
   WHERE nx.client_id = oo.client_id -- the same client
   AND nx.order_date > oo.order_date -- ,but with a more recent date
   );
```